# Bash declare associative array through function gives non-associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I tried to declare an associative array through a function, and I found that the associative array becomes a plain array. The test code goes like this:

```sh
bash-5.0$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

createArr(){ declare -A "$1"; }

# create array using `createArr'
name=array1
createArr $name
array1[1]=1
echo "${!array1[@]}"
array1[a]=1
echo "${!array1[@]}"
declare -p array1

# create array directly
name=array2
declare -A $name
array2[1]=1
echo "${!array2[@]}"
array2[a]=1
echo "${!array2[@]}"
declare -p array2
```

And executing the code gives the following result:

```sh
bash-5.0$ ./test.sh
1
0 1
declare -a array1=([0]="1" [1]="1")
1
1 a
declare -A array2=([1]="1" [a]="1" )
```

I'd like to know why the results are different, thanks! (My bash version is 5.0.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`help declare` says

> When used in a function, `declare` makes NAMEs **local**, as with the `local` command.

That means outside of `createArr`, `array1` is not declared. And an assignment like `array1[1]=1` where `array1` is unset, implies that `array1` is a regular, indexed array.

Using the `-g` flag in your function fixes this though

```
createArr() { declare -gA "$1"; }
```